# Most efficient way to remove a node on a single linked list?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am implementing a single linked list of integer and I was wondering what is the most efficient way to locate a given value and remove it from the list. This is what I have so far:

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;

  public void insert(int value){
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = value;
    newNode.next = null;

    if(head==null){
      head = newNode;
    } else {
      Node iterator = head;
      while(iterator.next!=null){
        iterator = iterator.next;
      }
      iterator.next = newNode;
    }
  }

  public void display(LinkedList list){
    Node iterator = head;
    while (iterator!=null){
      System.out.println(iterator.data);
      iterator = iterator.next;
    }
  }

  public void remove(LinkedList list, int value){
    Node iterator = head;
    while(iterator!=null){
      if(iterator.next.data == value){
          iterator.next = iterator.next.next;
      } else{
        iterator = iterator.next;
      }
    }
  }
}


public class Node {
  int data;
  Node next;
}
```

Comment: Will throw NPE.

Comment: Maybe you should remove LinkedList list from the parameters, since you don't use it.

Comment: Correct, I got NPE, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `iterator.next` could be null, as well as `iterator.next.next`. Also, what is `head`? It isn't defined in your code.

Comment: I just added everything, thanks

Comment: You could check if iterator.next is null. Which will happen whenever your value is not found in the list. Also, you never check the current node, ie head could contain the value and it would be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding snippet here to remove the node from SinglyLinkedList. I prefer forLoop over while; that's the reason I have added snippet with for loop.

Hope the comment in the code helps you to navigate/dry run the snippet.

```
public boolean remove(int value){ 
 Node oneBeforeValueNode;
 // Using for to iterate through the SinglyLinkedList
 // head → is the head of your SingleLinkedList
 for (Node node = head; node != null; node = node.next) {
      // Compare the value with current node
      if (value.equals(node.data)) {
            // if matches then unlink/remove that node from SinglyLinkedList
            // if its a first node in SingleLinkedList
            if(oneBeforeValueNode==null){
              // Considering there exists next element else SLL will be empty
              head = head.next;
            } else {
              // if there exists next element it SLL it will attach that element with previous one
              oneBeforeValueNode.next = node.next;
            }
            return true;
       }
     // Storing previous node from current
     // To use it once value is found to reference it to current.next(node.next)
     oneBeforeValueNode = node;
   }
 return false;
}
```

Adding with while variant as well; just to go with your flow.

```
public Node remove(Node head, int key) {
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;
        while (current != null) {
            if(current.data == key) {

                if(current == head) {
                    head = head.next;
                    current = head;

                } else {
                    previous.next = current.next;
                    current = current.next;
                }

            } else {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }
```